# How to visualise / what would be the cross product of 2 vectors with different initial point?

Tags: vectors

[image]

Normally my teacher would tell me to do $\vec{AB}$ x $\vec{AC}$ which have the same initial point and the cross product of that would be the line/vector perpendicular to the plane or perpendicular to those 2 vectors.

But in this question, we have different initial point. What does this mean and how can i visualise this? Does this have to do with: [image]   ?

Answer (score 1):

Vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}=B-A=(-1,-3,1)$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}=C-A=(0,-2,1)$ can be viewed as vectors starting at the origin therefore nothing change in the calculation for dot or cross product. In other words, in both cases we can consider $A$ as the origin for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry i think i might not have addressed my question properly, my question should have been the difference $\vec{AB}$ x $\vec{BC}$ and $\vec{AB}$ x $\vec{AC}$

Comment: @FredWeasley For all these vectors we can proceed as usual we always can assume the first point as the origin for that vector.